# Lenovo IdeaPad3 touchpad does not work

Tags: 20.10, mousepad

The problem that I can't solve myself is the following:

I bought a new piece of hardware and installed the latest Ubuntu on it. During the installation, I had my external mouse (Logitech) connected. Everything was smooth, but after playing with some options, I realized my touchpad is not working properly. It is actually being recognized, but when you try to navigate it, everything moves in pieces.

This is my mouse:

```sh
sudo xinput list 13
**MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Mouse**                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
```

After reading some posts I've tried few different things among which is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs
```

for `/etc/default/grub` -> `update-grub`, `reboot`, but it actually prevents the system from booting later on.

Has anybody encountered the same problem? If yes, please do suggest the next move.

Comment: get info as listed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 0):

please disregard the post above, issue got solved after updating the kernel to 5.12.*

Apparently Ubuntu 20.1 ships with 5.8 which has problems and there are bugs opened for that. I am not sure if I can post links here so I won't If anybody is interested i can provide them.

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors, but Chinese technology and English software that you are trying to make friends with each other. Their moral aspects are in the process of being realized and cannot yet find a clear answer to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IIL05. In order to make the touchpad work on 20.04 I edit grub with pci:nocrs and it's fine. But when I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, the touchpad does not work and editing the grub causes a black screen during boot with an initramfs CLI ... it's impossible to boot. This is the info of the touchpad:

cat /proc/bus/input/devices

MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE2D Touchpad

I don't know if you have the same problem on 22.04 or even if we have the same model of IdeaPad 3

Comment: Thats right. Its a problem with kernel 5.15 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056. I have lenovo 15IIL