# Touchpad does not work on Lenovo Laptop

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

good afternoon!

Lenovo Ideapad 3-15ALC6 notebook touchpad stopped working after switching OS.

The notebook comes from the factory with a discontinued distribution of linux - Satux. So far the touchpad was working fine. Then I switched to Fedora 35 and for a while it was working too, until I updated the system and it stopped working altogether.

After doing research on the internet, I tried to solve it with the following techniques:

1. Liveboot a newer Fedora distribution (36) - Negative
2. Live boot with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Negative
3. I ended up taking Fedora out and installing Ubuntu on it.

With Ubuntu installed, I found [this article](https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-%2004/) where I found that the problem might be in the Kernel. Right after installing Ubuntu the Kernel version was 5.15.0. I did the [Kernel upgrade](https://www.kernel.org/) to the latest version which at the time of writing this text was 5.18.6. For this, I followed the steps in the article above, but without result.

Also I took a look at similar [issue reported in the past](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321517/lenovo-ideapad3-touchpad-does-not-work) where upgrading kernel solved the problema. But this is not my case as my kernel is already up to date.

The touchpad still doesn't work. As it is a new machine and it arrived with the touchpad working, I believe it is a driver support issue. I contacted Lenovo technical assistance, but the technicians said that they will have to collect the machine and change the touch.

I believe this is not the problem

I record my hardware data here:

```
description: notebook
product: 82MF (LENOVO_MT_82MF_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad 3 15ALC6)
manufacturer: LENOVO
version: IdeaPad 3 15ALC6
serial: PE089AG9
width: 64 bit
capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=2808 Product=0101 Version=0100
N: Name="MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Mouse"
Q: Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:2808:0101.0001/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=2808 Product=0101 Version=0100
N: Name="MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad"
Q: Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:2808:0101.0001/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

AMD Ryzen 5 processor.

If anyone knows how I can tackle this problem in a different way, please help me. Or if there is someone who bought the same notebook and is having the same problem, let's share information.

**update 23-06-2022**

I ran `xinput` and looks like my touchpad did not show up:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here is an output from `sudo libinput list-devices | grep Device`:

```
Device:           Power Button
Device:           Video Bus
Device:           Power Button
Device:           Lid Switch
Device:           Integrated Camera: Integrated C
Device:           Ideapad extra buttons
Device:           MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad
Device:           MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Mouse
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Device:           JBL TUNE125BT (AVRCP)
Device:           M720 Triathlon Keyboard
Device:           M720 Triathlon Mouse
Device:           MX Keys Keyboard
Device:           MX Keys Mouse
```

Here are touchpad specific details:

```
Device:           MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             100x67mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

There is also some unknown mouse. I do not know what mouse is it, because the only mouse I use is a bluetooth mouse M720 Triathlon Mouse

```
Device:           MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

**Update 25-06-2022**
Output from `cat /var/log/syslog | grep touchpad` looks ok.

```
Jun 25 09:58:04 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 09:58:04 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 09:58:04 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:06:01 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:07:53 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:21:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1712]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 10:21:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1712]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:21:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1712]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:28:00 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1712]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:29:34 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5312]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 10:29:34 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5312]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:29:34 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5312]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:29:52 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6147]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 10:29:52 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6147]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:29:52 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6147]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:33:37 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[993]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 10:33:37 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[993]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:33:37 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[993]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:34:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1769]: (**) MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
Jun 25 10:34:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1769]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Jun 25 10:34:27 red-wine /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1769]: (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 2808:0101 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
```

Comment: does xinput at command line show it?
if it does
xinput enable <ID#>

Comment: Have you checked your function keys to make sure the touchpad is not disabled?

Comment: @pierrely thanks for reply! I attached a `xinput` output to my question. Looks like touchpad are missing.

Comment: You are on wayland. You need ```sudo libinput list-devices``` instead of ```xinput```. ```grep "Device"``` for shorter output. Repost the output please

Comment: Hi @UnderTheHoud. Thank you for reply. I provided the information you asked.

Comment: Also I observed that after reboot the touchpad button works on login screen. The trackpad still without response. But the buttons work properly. Buttons stop to work as soon as I login to the system.

Comment: Do you have some errors in ```cat /var/log/syslog | grep touchpad``` ? Is the device enabled in Settings > Mouse&Touchpad > Touchpad?

Comment: experiment with Wayland on or off?
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Comment: Nothing helped. There is no alarm in `cat /var/log/syslog | grep touchpad`.

I attached output to my question. Looks like the hardware is detected, but it does not work at all. No gestures, buttons or something like this. :(

Comment: When I tried to test touchpad with `evtest /dev/input/event6` it receives only button click events. When I tried to use gestures, no event are received.

Comment: I saw this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056 that seems to be related to your problem (also an ideapad 3). The touchpad worked with kernel 5.13.0-40-lowlatency and ```pci=nocrs``` in ```etc/default/grub```. But had problems with kernel 5.14, 5.15, 5.17 (changing this parameter lead to boot problems)... The bug is not solved yet and very recent. I would suggest you to try a kernel 5.13 but read this carefully it might be helpful

Comment: @UnderTheHoud thanks for sharing this thread! Very helpfull indeed =)

Comment: @UnderTheHoud I tried  kernel 5.13.0-40-lowlatency with `pci=nocrs`. Touchpad still down and wifi desappear as well. So I rolled back to my previous kernel and remove `pci=nocrs`. Hope this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: I wonder if touchegg would pick anything up?